# How can you specify a ProjectionExpression for the GetItem operation using the DynamoDb Enhanced Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to retrieve a single item (GetItem) from a DynamoDB table using the [AWS Java SDK Enhanced Dynamod DB client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/dynamodb-enhanced-client.html) but I'm interested in just a subset of its attributes. Normally I'd use a projection expression to do so but I can't seem to figure out how one can achieve this when using the [DynamoDb Enhanced client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/DynamoDbEnhancedClient.html#table-java.lang.String-software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema-).

The [GetItemEnhancedRequest](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/model/GetItemEnhancedRequest.html) method associated with the enhanced client lacks many of the features exposed by the [GetItemRequest](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/model/GetItemRequest.html) method of the base client (including the ability to specify a [projection expression](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/model/GetItemRequest.html#projectionExpression--))

There are, ofc, many workarounds (including the straight up use of the methods exposed by the base client) but I'm just curious if I'm missing something obvious from the enhanced client functionality.

Thank you